# AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'add_internal'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am quite new to pygame and I have a problem where I cannot add an image to a group. I don't know why it doesn't work.

The code is supposed to create a box at (10,10). I am using python 3.4.4 and pygame 1.9.1.

Can somebody show me what I have done wrong?

```
import pygame, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 100))

tile_l1_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

image = pygame.image.load("box.png")
image = image.convert_alpha()
a=screen.blit(image, (10,10))
pygame.display.flip()
tile_l1_list.add(image)


####################################

while True:
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is attempting to add the Surface image into the sprite Group tile_l1_list, instead create a Sprite instance with a sprite.image attribute and add this to the sprite Group. This snippet demonstrates the Sprite class using your code's 'image' and 'screen' instances, though it is preferable to subclass Sprite:

```
tile_l1_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
tile = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
tile.image = image
tile.rect = image.get_rect()
tile.rect.x = 10
tile.rect.y = 10
tile_l1_list.add(tile)
tile_l1_list.draw(screen)
pygame.display.flip()
```